# Elastic search throwing Client client error response with searches

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have someone which is going around probing for sql injections, which is fine, but I am finding elastic search is throwing errors which I thought the library would just handle.

For example if someone does a search for

```
' or 1=1 ' --
```

then I get

```
exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException' with message 'Client error response
[status code] 400
[reason phrase] Bad Request
[url] http://localhost:9200/items/product/_search' in /.../vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Http/Exception/BadResponseException.php:43
```

If we look at the code which is doing the search we have

```
    $client = new Client();
    $products = $client->search([
        'index' => 'product',
        'type' => 'product',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'query_string' => [
                    'query' => $query,
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

where $query is equal to `' or 1=1 ' --`

So, how come the query doesn't get escaped, why is it throwing an error and what should I do to stop it? I also get people trying to throw in other stuff trying to execute some scripts or something through the search.

I don't need fancy options (like foo -bar)

Running elasticsearch/elasticsearch v1.1.0 php library
Running elasticsearch v1.7.1 on the server

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
```

Comment: Where is the ClientBuilder class?

Comment: are you using elasicsearch-php? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/_index_management_operations.html